# Sprite Kit: Game menu prefrences. Using a separate scene for the menu, an offscreen node or UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, menu, sprite-kit

Just wanted your opinions on this. I am leaning towards UIView to hold my main menu and such, and just displaying it over the SKView when appropriate. Or I can have an offscreen node with the menu, or I can make a whole new SKScene to transition to.

Do you have any other alternatives or advice on the topic?

If we want to be specific about the scope of the game. It will be something along the lines of an infinite runner. So the menu would be pretty simple (Start, leaderboard... etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also developing a SpriteKit game and also needed to display a menu with options and a settings menu, in my case, I found it better to use UiView to present most of the settings of the game as well as a tutorial view because it is a UipageViewController (to present images for how the game works) but here is the downside of either option:

- If you choose to use views for menus and pause the game then the rootController must present it and any buttons, labels, images, etc must be presented and then removed, otherwise they will still sit on top of content. This works but animating stuff is difficult, unlike with another Skcene where elements like buttons can bounce, move, etc
- The downside of using Skscene is that simple Ui-elements, like those I mentioned before, are now difficult to work with. For example instead of having a button you now have a node and you must therefore work with the touches methods: began, moving, and ending to make the node behave as a touch-up-inside button. Same with labels, and everything will have to be done programmatically whereas if you want to use views, you could make them in he storyboard and instantiate them as needed.

Conclusion: In my game I only chose to use Skscene for the game itself, (i.e playing) and used the views for pause, settings, about, tutorial. Hope this gives you some idea!

Comment: Very nice points, thanks. I think this particular game I am making will do fine with UI Kit elements.

Answer (score 0):

I initially started out with all these non-gameplay scenes as UIViews/UIViewControllers, but later on switched to having everything as an SKScene except for the welcome scene viewcontroller.

It doesn't seem very difficult having the options/settings/high scores type of screens under the SKScene option.  You really only need to use one method to detect the UITouch:

```
touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

This works great with sklabels.  You could easily load a spritekitnode behind the sklabel and get the same full effects of the `UIButton` with this combination.  You can of course all all touch methods, but touchesBegan almost mimics the expected behavior.

With these views under an SKScene, you also get access to the update: method where you can get more creative in how you display animations and events.

Comment: Please format your code parts properly. Like `UIView`. The text is quite hard to read.